# Neo4j community edition installation problem HostnamePortTest failure

Tags: scala, neo4j

I tried to install two versions of Neo4j community edition (4.2.0-SNAPSHOT and 4.1.4-SNAPSHOT).
Both are failing with these errors:

```
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   HostnamePortTest.testGetHostAddressUnknown:121 Expected java.net.UnknownHostException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   HostnamePortTest.testMatchesIPWithHostUnknown:267 Expected java.net.UnknownHostException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   HostnamePortTest.testMatchesKnownHostWithHostUnknown:332 Expected java.net.UnknownHostException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   HostnamePortTest.testMatchesNullHostWithUnknownHost:387 Expected java.net.UnknownHostException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   HostnamePortTest.testMatchesUnknownHosts:135 Expected java.net.UnknownHostException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 222, Failures: 5, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I can finish the installation with skip tests flag enabled but later when I try to connect to Neo4j I'm getting these errors:

```
[error] Oct 08, 2020 10:50:19 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
[error] INFO: Direct driver instance 1881901842 created for server address localhost:7687
[error] Oct 08, 2020 10:50:19 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
[error] INFO: Closing driver instance 1881901842
[error] Oct 08, 2020 10:50:19 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
[error] INFO: Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687
```

Can someone help, I'm not sure what are these errors about?
Thanks,

Joe

Comment: How are you installing neo4j? Why are you building from source and why using not stable versions? And what does Scala has todo with this?

Comment: If multiple installations need to run at the same time on the same machine, make sure their services are configured to listen on different [ports](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/ports/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Neo4j community edition works fine even though test cases produce errors. I'm still not sure where are those errors coming from, they don't make much sense.
As for the second part it looks like Neo4j Java driver is printing INFO messages as ERROR messages to console ([error] INFO: Closing driver instance 1496355635). Again I'm not sure why.
My solution was to skip test cases during installation with this command:
mvn install -DskipTests

Comment: Unless you are actually doing development on some aspect of the neo4j ecosystem, you should not be building neo4j. See [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/) for how to install pre-built versions of neo4j.